# Logrotate wildcard fails on missing files with "missingok" AND "olddir"

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, logrotate

## Platform:

```
RHEL 7
logrotate-3.8.6-7.el7_2.x86_64
```

## Background:

On a RedHat Linux server I have a large set of application servers running, and want a uniform logrotate routine for cleaning up log files. Using wildcards is paramount so I don't have to maintain a constantly growing and shrinking list.

## Issue:

Combining wildcards, the "missingok" option AND "olddir" does not seem to work. When I define a pattern for debug log files - which may or may not exist - and only use "missingok", everything is fine.
If I add the "olddir" option it fails with:

```
# logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/foobar
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/foobar
olddir is now old_logs
error: /etc/logrotate.d/foobar:28 error verifying log file path /srv/www/servers/*/logs: No such file or directory
removing last 1 log configs
```

The config file:

```
/srv/www/servers/*/logs/*_foobar.txt
{
  daily
  olddir old_logs
  missingok
}
```

I see there has been a long standing fix in http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2008-0703.html fixing the issue with wildcard and missingok, but has anybody seen or fixed the issue with olddir?

I'm considering skipping olddir and using postrotate + find/mv, but I would like not having to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed upstream: https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/commit/73493ec38c5e806fa66d8c3f13259775da6282d9

Quote:

```
Fix 'olddir' usage with wildcard in the middle of path in the pattern…
… definition when the pattern did not match any log file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue.

Watch directory with /var/logs/*/*/*.log
and use the "missingok"  and "olddir" together.

If there's no any log under that directory, it will complain:

error verifying log file path /var/logs/*/*: No such file or directory

@sastorsl  how do you do then?

Mine logrotate 3.7.8.

It seems has been fixed in 3.11.0.